# JLayout Search Tool not populating filters and inputbx

Tags: joomla-3.x, filter, jlayout

I am converting the searchbar in one of my components to JLayout Search Tools searchbars to become more ready for J!4. Everything is working fine but it is not populating the filters.

**In view.html.php I have this**:

```
    $this->state         = $this->get('State');
    $this->filterForm    = $this->get('FilterForm');
    $this->activeFilters = $this->get('ActiveFilters');

    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
    {
        throw new Exception(implode("\n", $errors), 500);
    }
```

$this->state / $this->filterForm / $this->ActiveFilters are populated.

**In my filter_categories.xml file I have this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
<fields name="filter">
    <field
            name="search"
            type="text"
            label="Search"
            hint="Filter"
    />

    <field
            name="published"
            type="list"
            label="COM_CONTENT_FILTER_PUBLISHED"
            description="COM_CONTENT_FILTER_PUBLISHED_DESC"
            onchange="this.form.submit();"
    >
        <option value="">Select Publishing State</option>
        <option value="1">Published</option>
        <option value="0">Unpublished</option>
    </field>
</fields>

<fields name="list">
    <field
            name="limit"
            type="limitbox"
            class="input-mini"
            default="25"
            label="COM_CONTENT_LIST_LIMIT"
            description="COM_CONTENT_LIST_LIMIT_DESC"
            onchange="this.form.submit();"
    />
</fields>
</form>
```

**Then in the model I have:**

```
function __construct($config = [])
{
    if (empty($config['filter_fields']))
    {
        $config['filter_fields'] = [
            'published', 'a.published',
            'search', 'a.search',
        ];
    }

    parent::__construct($config);

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    $start = $this->getState('list.start', $app->getUserStateFromRequest('limitstart', 'limitstart', 0, 'int'));
    $limit = $this->getState('list.limit', JFactory::getApplication()->get('list_limit'));
    $total = $this->getTotal();

    if ($start > $total - $limit)
    {
        $start = max(0, (int) (ceil($total / $limit) - 1) * $limit);
    }

    $this->setState('list.start', $start);
    $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);

    $cid      = $app->input->get('cid', [0], 'array');
    $this->id = (int) $cid[0];
}

protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
{
    $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
    $this->setState('filter.search', $search);

    $state = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.published', 'filter_published');
    $this->setState('filter.state', $state);

    $limit = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.limit', 'filter_limit', '');
    $this->setState('filter.limit', $limit);

    parent::populateState('a.id', 'asc');
}

protected function getStoreId($id = '')
{
    // Compile the store id.
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.search');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.published');

    return parent::getStoreId($id);
}
```

Filters works like a charm, and it is filtering as expected. But when the users comes back in the page after filtering the search is for example empty.

As you can see in the screenshot, I have searched for Easy, one result (which is correct is being returned) Everything looks OK. But the search input box in the middle is empty after using the filter. Also the publishing is not set to the correct option.

[image]

Comment: This page seems related, but I don't think it contains a solution for you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24388406/2943403 I'm only adding it in case it could help trigger new ideas.

Comment: This is something different than my question. Not problem, thank you for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change view.html.php to:

```
$model = $this->getModel();
$this->items         = $model->getItems();
$this->filterForm    = $model->getFilterForm();
$this->activeFilters = $model->getActiveFilters();
$this->state         = $model->getState();
$this->pagination    = $model->getPagination();
```

And regarding your model: which Joomla Class do you extend? ListModel?

Comment: This is also not working :( I am using the JModelList